# How to instantiate an instance of redis only during runtime (i.e. while JUnits are being run)

Tags: java, spring, junit, redis

As it is now, my JUnits point to an instance of redis running on a server. So as to relieve the tests from this dependency, I was asked to figure out how to run redis in memory while the JUnits ran - will someone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Redis can't be run purely in memory. The best you can do is run the Redis process on the same machine your Junits are running and attach to it using localhost.

You could also mock the functionality of Redis if your application accesses it through an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could start redis before your tests run. This is a common way (e. g. using a [Makefile](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/blob/master/Makefile)) which could result in:

- `make start` (build, configure and start redis)
- `make test`
- `make stop` (stop redis)